# Add and name column in a dataset

Tags: stata

I'm trying in Stata to add columns to my dataset and name them `year_2005`,..., `year_2017`.

Here is my code:

```
gen a=.
forvalues i=2005(1)2015 {
    replace a=(b>i)
    rename a "year"+`i'
}
```

`b` is a numeric variable in my dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do this:

```
clear
set obs 1

forvalues i = 1 / 15 {
    if `i' < 10 local d 0
    generate year_20`d'`i' = runiform()
}
```

Or alternatively (as per @NickCox comment - see [Stata tip 85](https://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=pr0051)):

```
clear
set obs 1

forvalues i = 1 / 15 {  
   generate year_20`: display %02.0f `i'' = runiform()
}
```

Or using your example:

```
clear
set obs 1

forvalues i = 2005(1)2015 {
    generate a = .
    replace a =  runiform()
    rename a year_`i'
}
```